# Find the directory contains mouse in xlib

Tags: xlib

I can detect the mouse location by using XQueryPointer. Now I want to know the location of the directory that contains my mouse.
Is there any way to do this ?

Thank you!

Comment: "location of the directory that contains my mouse"? - Are you talking about directory as in "/dev/input/mice" path?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. For example: I open /home/username/test. And I click on one coordinate of that window. I can know that location

Comment: Use XQueryTree, then look at `WM_NAME` property of each window, and use XGetWindowAttributes to get coordinates of each window

Comment: Hi, I can get the Coordinate of the window, But how can I get the location path of that window ?

Comment: If it's displayed in the title - use WM_NAME. Otherwise might not be possible

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I'm having this problem: "I drag a file from my Qt program to Desktop. I want to know the drop location, so I can download to that location. But it seem not possible in Linux. I hear that it is ok in Windows" So sad

Comment: IMO drop target should be responsible for this

Comment: Yes, but in my case. The file is not available in my PC.It's still in the server and I need to download that file to tmp folder. After that, copy downloaded file to drop location